# How to write a function to update a specific value, from input values, to Firebase RD in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, patch

[image: Firebase databas with 3 products and 3 cities with a stock value]

Here is Firebase database with product-then Klocka(watch), Platta(ipad), Telefon(mobile)
I want to update the value of each cities stock when choose a product in input and select fields.
[image: Front page woth input and select fields]

How can I write the function to change the selected value in the database? I have started with a function but dont know how to continue. How can I make the database understand its this selected value that should be changed to the new value?
main.js
//get data from Firebase

```
async function products(){
  try{
    const baseURL = 'https://paronab-79d88-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/'
    const url = baseURL + 'product.json'
    const response = await fetch(url)
    let data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    
    
    localStorage.setItem("getdata", JSON.stringify(data))
    const lagretidag = document.querySelector('.lagretidag')
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => 
        lagretidag.innerHTML += `
        <div class="produkt-container">
        <p>Produkt: ${key}</p>
        <p> Frankfurt: ${value.Frankfurt}</p>
        <p> Cupertino: ${value.Cupertino}</p> 
        <p> Norrköping: ${value.Norrköping}</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        `
        
    )

   
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }

  }
products()
```

//Get values from input and select fields, save in localStorage

```
const euro = document.querySelectorAll('.euro')
function change1(){
    const input1 = document.querySelector('.input1').value
    const input2 =  document.querySelector('.input2').value
    const select = document.getElementById('select').value
    const select2 = document.getElementById('select2').value
    
    console.log(input1, input2, select)

    const arr = new Array();
    arr.push({input1, input2, select, select2});

    localStorage.setItem("myArray", JSON.stringify(arr));  

}
```

cart.js
//Get data from localStorage and render in DOM

```
let productGrid = document.querySelector('.grid')


   
      let str = localStorage.getItem('myArray')
      arr = JSON.parse(str)
      console.log(arr)
  
  

    Object.entries(arr).forEach( ([key, value]) =>
      productGrid.innerHTML += `
      <div class="product">Produkt: ${value.select2}</div>
      <div class="quantity">Antal ta bort: -${value.input1}</div>
      <div class="quantity">Antal lägga till: +${value.input2}</div>
      <div>Stad: ${value.select}</div>`
    )
```

//buttons with empty changes and send changes to database

```
productGrid.innerHTML += `<button onclick="emptyCart()">Töm ändringar</button>`
productGrid.innerHTML += `<button onclick="checkout(id)">Ändra i lagret</button>`
```

// Empty changes

```
function emptyCart(){
  let productGrid = document.querySelector('.grid')
  productGrid.innerHTML = ''
  localStorage.clear();
}
```

//Get data from localstorage

```
const getData = localStorage.getItem('getdata')
const parseData = JSON.parse(getData)
console.log(parseData)
```

const select2 = localStorage.getItem('select2')
const input2 = localStorage.getItem('input2')

//send changes to firebase

```
function checkout(){

        
          
          async function updateSelectValue(select2, input2) {
            try {
              const baseURL = 'https://paronab-79d88-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/'
              const url = baseURL + 'product.json'
              const response = await fetch(url)
              let data = await response.json()
          
              // Update the 'select' value based on 'select2'
              Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
                if (data[key].select2 === select2) {
                  data[key].select = select + input2;
                }
              });
          
              // Send the updated data back to Firebase
              const updateResponse = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'PUT', // Use PUT to update the entire data
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: {
                  'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                },
              });
          
              if (updateResponse.ok) {
                console.log('Data updated successfully in Firebase!');
              } else {
                console.error('Failed to update data in Firebase.');
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error while updating data:', error);
            }
          }
          
          // Usage example: Call the updateSelectValue function to update 'select' based on 'select2'
          updateSelectValue('select2', 'select');
        emptyCart()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to (for example) set the value of `/Klocka/Cupertino` to 91,000, you can do that with the following call:

```
const baseURL = 'https://paronab-79d88-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/';
fetch(baseUrl+'product/Klocka/Cupertino.json', {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: JSON.stringify(91000),
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
});
```

So you can see that we pass the path to the data to write in the URL, and then end the URL with `.json` to make it clear to Firebase that we're accessing its REST API.

Comment: Thank you, I have now made it dynamic for every product and city I choose. But it changes to a string in the database. I have tried different JSON values like JSON.parse it doesnt change the value in firebase. How can I save JSON.stringify(input2) as a intiger?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wrote input2 in the body and it worked, because its saved as a number in the input field :)